# How to clear multiple list or dict together

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have large number of list and dictionary which need to be clear at each iteration. I am trying to write a function `GlobalClear` that have a list which contains the name of the list or dictionary to be clear. For example:

```
Result1={"d11":"1","d12":"2"}
Result2 =["l11","l22"]

def length(name):
    print(str(name) + "  having length is : "+ str(len(name)))

def GlobalClear():
    overallList = ["Result1", "Result2"]
    for key in overallList:
        list(key).clear()
        length(list(key))

print("Prev Length")
length(Result1)
length(Result2)
GlobalClear()
print("Final Length")
length(Result1)
length(Result2)
```

Output:

```
Prev Length
{'d11': '1', 'd12': '2'}  having length is : 2
['l11', 'l22']  having length is : 2
['R', 'e', 's', 'u', 'l', 't', '1']  having length is : 7
['R', 'e', 's', 'u', 'l', 't', '2']  having length is : 7
Final Length
{'d11': '1', 'd12': '2'}  having length is : 2
['l11', 'l22']  having length is : 2
```

Expected Output:

```
Prev Length
{'d11': '1', 'd12': '2'}  having length is : 2
['l11', 'l22']  having length is : 2
Final Length
{'d11': '1', 'd12': '2'}  having length is : 0
['l11', 'l22']  having length is : 0
```

Please suggest me suitable approach to handle the above problem. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing the names of the list, you can store a reference to the list itself and call `clear()` on that

```
Result1={"d11":"1","d12":"2"}
Result2 =["l11","l22"]

def length(name):
    print(str(name) + "  having length is : "+ str(len(name)))

def GlobalClear():
    overallList = [Result1, Result2]
    for key in overallList:
        key.clear()

print("Prev Length")
length(Result1)
length(Result2)
GlobalClear()
print("Final Length")
length(Result1)
length(Result2)
```

Output:

```
Prev Length
{'d11': '1', 'd12': '2'}  having length is : 2
['l11', 'l22']  having length is : 2
Final Length
{}  having length is : 0
[]  having length is : 0
```